# how to execute the ffmpeg with php

Tags: php

```
    $output = array();

    exec('ffmpeg -i "test.mp4" 2>&1', $output, $retVar);        
    $output = join(PHP_EOL, $output);
    echo $output;
```

hello, I have test this code but I always have the answer " ' ffmpeg' is not recognized as internal or external order, an executable program or a file of orders " and yet in the DOS it displays me information of the video.
NB: I have download ffmpeg static and I defined him in variables of environments and that functions very well.
I hope that you will understand my English.

Comment: Does this command works if you type it directly in your terminal ?

Comment: Close vote vor "lacks sufficient information..." ???? The problem is clear, isn't it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try and add the full path to the *ffmpeg* executable in the PHP script. This should solve your issue if you have *ffmpeg* installed already. The PHP executes the commands in different contexts and it may be missing the path to execute *ffmpeg* directly without a path before it.